# Django admin form can be manipulated with Cross-Site Request Forgery (CSRF)

Tags: python, django, security, csrf

In my Django admin site, I run a vulnerability test and it shows the following threat:

```
An effective CSRF (Cross-Site Request Forgery) countermeasure for forms is to 
include a hidden field with a random value specific to the user's current session.
A form was detected that did not appear to contain an anti-CSRF token. 
This form was tested for susceptibility to a CSRF attack and determined to be vulnerable.
```

I check in my admin pages; there CSRF is already set.

Comment: What is the test you are running, and the version of django?

Comment: QUALYS Web Application Vulnerability Scan, Django version is 1.8.2

Comment: You need to provide more details, as what was the URL that triggered the error. Instead of posting it here, send an email with all the details to `security@djangoproject.com`

Answer (score 0):

Automated tools often give false positives for Django's CSRF protection. The Django security team gets many invalid reports like this.